# Why does Tomcat not retrieve my session properly?

Tags: java, session, tomcat, http-headers

I have two Java applications running as servlets on Tomcat.

Application A creates a session on another application, application B.  Application A then uses a session cookie to log into application B.  This cookie is stored in a session variable and is used on subsequent logins:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
String cookieValue = session.getAttribute(sessionAttributeName);
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Cookie", cookieValue);
restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(headers), ProviderCostTOErrorWrapper.class);
```

This works fine.  But I need the ability to log in to application B using a rest client (I use PostMan).

So I created a service to get the session cookie for application B that is stored in application A's session.  It looks like this:

```
JSESSIONID=BF5C58B08062C84C648BA4DBE3A776BE; Path=/treatment/; HttpOnly
```

But when I log in to application b and inspect the session object, it has an entirely different id:

```
03A85C79914839E4F6D60B343B3535C4
```

It also has a different creation time.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Both the values are there for two different things.

> `JSESSIONID=BF5C58B08062C84C648BA4DBE3A776BE`
>   `SESSIONID=03A85C79914839E4F6D60B343B3535C4`

`JSessionId` and `SessionId` both are not same.

What you are considering as a `sessionId` is unique `String` defined by the `Servlet` container for every individual `HttpSession`.

On the other hand `JsessioId` is tracking parameter which can either be provided in `cookie` or `URL` by `Servlet` API. Which is defined when session is created. So, when you call `request.getSession()` or `request.getSession(true)`, session will be created and the `JSessionId` will be stored in cookie.

[`HttpSession#getId()`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getId()) returns the unique `String` defined for that particular `HttpSession`.